# SSH copy key from Raspberry Pi to Linux

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, raspbian, ssh-keygen

I am trying to create a new ssh key, and copy it to a server, using a previously generated ssh key.

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id  -f -i /home/pi/.ssh/newKey -o "IdentityFile=/home/pi/bob" user@host.edu
```

The following command is run using the rc.local (I also tried cron) and it will fail to copy the key to host.edu.  But if I run the same command after I login locally to the pi, then it runs fine.  How can I get this to run without logging onto the pi?

EDIT:

The rc.local runs the command is the pi user.

```
su pi -c '/home/pi/setup.sh'
```

Comment: did you schedule this command to run in the "user" of "pi" ? or in another user ? (e.g. root) you need to ensure that the user you schedule this command has the ability to read the key etc.

Comment: Yes, I run it as the pi user.

Comment: ok, and it might be a stupid question, but are you sure your shell script is executable ? also, can't you just deploy the key manually to the remote system ? (without using ssh-copy-id, but copying and pasting the public key manually)

Comment: I dont want to do this manually for 100-1000 unique raspberry pi's.  THere are multiple items that happen in the setup, and they all run, like the generation of a new ssh key.

Comment: add one more line, to login to int, and then copy-id :) ssh -l user host.edu exit